# Selenium - Looping through nested div - stale element reference

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

python

```
    row = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(CatalogPage.resultsTable_row_cssClass)
    columns = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div") ## this kind of works.
```

The row object is good.

columns: collects all the nested (double & triple) div inside a row , 20 of them by. So it is collecting the divs with an error Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. Nothing is actually changing on the page.    Note: Pycharm shows, columns, is a list of len 20. But looking at each object/element of the list, It's full of these errors. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJJf.png

According to [documentation], the reference is supposedly lost(https://www.selenium.dev/exceptions/#stale_element_reference).

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
icon_counter = {"success":0, "failed":0, "pending":0}

if columns[17].find_element_by_class_name(icon_class_name):
   icon_counter["success"] += 1
```

.html

```
<div id="row-ac253ecd-8a8a-4b58-9a7a-fa2d2bcc619b" role="row" class="rdt_TableRow">
    <div id="cell-aanda" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="dkc rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents"><button type="button" class="ant-btn round-sm"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor"><path d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"></path></svg></button></div></div>
    <div id="cell-cc19b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="afk rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents"><div>064</div></div></div>
    <div id="cell-c619b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="pka rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents">ECHO_CINEMATIC_RISE_STRESSMETALS</div></div>
    <div id="cell-qg69b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="gla rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents"><div><p class="tag"></p></div></div></div>
    <div id="cell-c619b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="awe rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents">N/A</div></div>
    <div id="cell-8ea1b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="haw rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents"><div class="d-flex"><span class="bg-pending round-sm mx-1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor"><path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></path></svg></span></div></div></div>
    <div id="cell-O619b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="ara rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents"><button type="button" class="ant-btn bg-success round-sm mx-1 no-border"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor"><path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z"></path></svg></button></div></div>
    <div id="cell-V019b" role="gridcell" data-tag="allowRowEvents" class="dad rdt_TableCell"><div data-tag="allowRowEvents"><div class="d-flex"><a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="/administration/tracks/ac253ecd-8a8a-4b58-9a7a-fa2d2bcc619b"><button type="button" class="ant-btn square-sm"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor"><path d="M10.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0z"></path><path d="M0 8s3-5.5 8-5.5S16 8 16 8s-3 5.5-8 5.5S0 8 0 8zm8 3.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7z"></path></svg></button></a></div></div></div>
</div>
```

visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDDsC.jpg

Comment: I don't understand how `column[17]` works. How could `column` be an array when you have defined `columns` as an array of webelements?

Comment: you're correct, that was a typo from a different snippet. corrected. The issue is that columns is full of 20 items (as it should be) but they all have stale element refernece

Comment: Somewhere between where you define and use `columns`, you must be navigating to another page, that's what causes the stale element reference.

Comment: @C.Peck nope. doing exactly that. Load page, apply filter, define row, define column, try to use column. no page changes or anything. good to know the approach is correct, will keep trying

Comment: you'll get a stale element exception when you call a method on a webelement reference that is stale.  So in your case it looks like the row.find_element... call is throwing the error.  (Which means the DOM is still updating when you call that.)  To test add a good sleep before getting the row webelement reference.

Comment: @pcalkins i got it working, not sure why it worked tbh. Fails occasionally, did adda. sleep, will have front end devs ad some ids so it's robust.

Comment: instead of sleep, you can try/catch your find element call on the row.  If stale element exception is caught, re-call find element to re-find row... re-call find element on row... (functionize it so you can re-call.)